# asset_repossessed icon not displaying

Tags: lightning-web-components, icon

I have a lightning-icon element:

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:asset_repossessed"></lightning-icon>
```

"asset_repossessed" is the only icon that doesn't show, what gives ?

[image]

Any other icon I try works just fine...

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:asset_warranty"></lightning-icon>
```

[image]

If you want the surrounding context here it is but I don't think that matters:

```
 <lightning-card>
        <template lwc:if={accountInfo.data}>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-m-around_large">
                <div class="slds-col  slds-size_2-of-8">
                    <template lwc:if={usingMaster}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:opportunity"></lightning-icon>
                    </template>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:asset_warranty"></lightning-icon>
                </div>
                 ...
```

Every other icon I try works:

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowdown"></lightning-icon>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asset_repossessed` is introduced in Spring '24 release of SLDS. Hence to get this working your org needs to be on the latest Spring '24 release.

You can sign up for a Spring 24 release org from [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring24/).

The other alternative is to manually download the icon SVG from the [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/) site and put this in the static resource and then use it as below

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'; 
import customIcon from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/asset_repossessed'; 

export default class CustomIconLWC extends LightningElement { 
   customIcon = customIcon + '#asset_repossessed';
}
```

HTML Template

```
<template>
    <div>customIcon</div>
    <lightning-icon src={customIcon}></lightning-icon>
</template>
```

Comment: Are icons mentioned in the release notes ? If so where ? If not how did you know about this ?

Comment: You can check the SLDS site and see that prior versions did not have them.

Comment: Also since I work for Salesforce it makes it easy for me to look at internal codebase and know this.

Comment: Always nice to have a cheat code. If I ever get a chance, I might have to apply :D